# Fisher Exact test - Can't replicate SPSS results in Excel

Tags: spss, excel, fishers-exact-test

I've been doing some Fisher Exact tests in SPSS and am trying to do in Excel instead. So i can do automatically for rows of data. But I can't get the Excel results to match the results from SPSS.

The way to do test in SPSS is quite straightforward. This describes it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MbTlee-He8

I'd like to know why i don't have the 'Exact' option that other tutorials mention:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KomStQDeraY

I'm following this method for the Excel:
https://www.real-statistics.com/chi-square-and-f-distributions/fishers-exact-test/

Focusing on the one-tail/side results, in excel I think i need to subtract the p-value from 1 sometimes, as i get values of 0.95 and above. I believe that these are significant results even though p is not < 0.05.

Then comparing the p-values, for 29 tests, i get up to 100% difference. Whether they are significant or not at the 0.05 level here is only 1 test that is different (0.07 in SPSS, 0.01 in Excel).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how i can do an appropriate method in both Excel and SPSS?

Thanks
Rob

[image: Fisher Test in Excel]

Comment: Can you give specific data you want to analyze, show SPSS results, and show Excel results?

Comment: Without seeing what you're doing it's hard to guess where your problem is.

Comment: I'm unsure how to make more specific since it seems impossible to upload an excel file. But I've added a picture related to the Answer that BruceET kindly provided

Comment: What is the $2\times 2$ table for _your_ data? Before you did the experiment, did you suppose that a _particular one_ of the two groups would have a higher proportion of Successes? // Some implementations of Fisher's Exact Test show results _only_ for two-tailed tests. (I don't know about Excel. No idea what $0.9959$ refers to. When beginning to use a procedure in unfamiliar software it is a good idea to start by tying to duplicate results of a couple of worked textbook examples.)

Comment: My data is company divisions and the category is male/female. I'm trying to calculate which directorates have significantly higher or lower proportion of females. So my 2 x 2 grids are Division/All Other Staff x Female/Male. Some divisions will have lower proportion of females (Analysis, Finance), and some will have higher (HR). Some will be very similar to the overall split (52% female).

Answer (score 5):

Debugging strange results from various kinds of software is off-topic here.
However, it may help you to figure out what is wrong, if I show output for Fisher's Exact Test as implemented in R. In the process you can try to learn the basics of Fisher's Exact Test. [You may also want to google the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) on Fisher's Exact Test. And @whuber's Answer [on this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232187/fishers-exact-test-help-understanding-the-p-value?rq=1) listed in the margin of the current page.]

*Example:* Suppose Group A has 100 subjects of whom 72 answered Yes to a question and the rest answered No. Also, Group B has 110 subjects of whom 61 answered Yes, the rest No.

Then you have a $2 \times 2$ table `TBL` of results as follows:

```
TBL = rbind(c(72, 28), c(61, 49));  TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   72   28
[2,]   61   49

fisher.test(TBL)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.009389
alternative hypothesis: 
 true odds ratio is greater than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.223936      Inf
sample estimates:
 odds ratio 
   2.058383
```

Group B has a significantly lower proportion of Yes's than does Group A.
With P-value $0.0094 < 0.01 = 1\%,$ you have significance at the 1% level.

This test uses row marginal totals 100 (Group A), 110 (Group B)
and the column marginal totals 133 (Yes) and 77 (No).
The essential question is:
"If I have 110 B's and 100 A's, what is the probability
of seeing 61 or fewer B's among 133 Yes's?"

This is a hypergeometric probability, equivalent to the following:
I have 110 green marbles (B's) in an urn and 110 red ones (A's). I withdraw
133 marbles (Yes's) without replacement, what is the probability I get
61 or fewer green ones.

The probability of getting *exactly* 61 Green marbles is
$P(X=61)=\frac{{110\choose 61}{100\choose 72}}{{210\choose 133}} =0,0052.$

The probability of gettine 61 or fewer is the P-value
$P(X \le 61)=\sum_{i=0}^{61} \frac{{110\choose i}{100\choose 133-i}}{{210\choose 133}} = 0.0094.$

```
dhyper(61, 110, 100, 133)  # hypergeom PDF
[1] 0.005246848

phyper(61, 110, 100, 133)  # hypergeom CDF
[1] 0.009388924
```

Traditionally, Fisher's Exact Test was used mainly for small counts (because of the tedious computations required for large counts), and
an (approximate) chi-squared test was used for larger counts. In case one of your programs is giving you results from a chi-squared test. In R the one-sided chi-square test is implemented as `prop.test`. The approximate P-value $0.0096,$ is not much different from the P-value for Fisher's Exact Test.

```
prop.test(c(72,61), c(100,110), alt="g")

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(72, 61) out of c(100, 110)
X-squared = 5.4829, df = 1, p-value = 0.009602
alternative hypothesis: greater
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.04853051 1.00000000
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.7200000 0.5545455
```

You might want to try data from my $2 \times 2$ table in SPSS and Excel
to see whether results differ from the results obtained using R above. You might also be able to find worked examples for Fisher's test in various elementary and intermediate applied statistics textbooks.

Comment: Thank you. I think what is happening is that when i do the test in Excel using the HYPGEOM distribution it gives you different results when you test whether the proportion of (up to) A successes is statistically significant, or whether the proportion of (up to A) fails is statistically significant. E.g. 0.996 vs 0.09. And the two values don't add up to 1. I thought it was the same test - just opposite so they should add up to 1.

But actually both tests include the probability of exactly the observed number of fails/successes so they don't sum to 1.

Comment: So i suppose i need to decide which direction i need to use the test. Maybe i should do a two tail test.

Comment: Hi I'm now trying to do the Fisher Exact tests in R and want to integrate them into PowerBI. I'm struggling to match my excel tests with those done by R.

Additionally, somehow I can't replicate your R results in R. 

TBL = rbind(c(72, 28), c(61, 49));  TBL
[,1] [,2]
[1,]   72   28
[2,]   61   49

fisher.test(TBL)

Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.01499
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.11818 3.84029
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  2.058383 

Do you have any ideas what could be happening?