chi-square test residuals vs Fisher's exact test
I am running chi-square tests on data with two categorical variables and had a question on obtaining the standardized residuals for a Fisher's exact test vs a chi-square test, to be able to identify which cells in a table drive the association (or not) between two variables.
How are the standardized residuals obtained in a Fisher's exact test, and does this differ from a chi square test?
What types of post hoc testing for Fisher's exact test can you run to obtain the standardized residuals and p-values?


You don't "run a test" to obtain standardized residuals. 2. The probability distribution for any individual cell entry is hypergeometric (which has a fairly straightforward mean and a standard deviation) but there's multiple other "residuals" that can be defined.


How many categories for each variable? Is it just a 2x2 contingency table, or nxm? In any case, there are really no "standardized residuals" per se for Fisher exact; you could use the $\chi^2$ residuals, but they do not correspond to anything the Fisher exact test does; see e.g.  https://www.reddit.com/r/AskStatistics/comments/iyy32m/can_you_use_standardized_residuals_as_a_posthoc/.  If you wanted a "Fisher-exact-ish" method to do post-hoc analysis, you could run a series of 2x2 Fisher-exact tests (1 combination against "everything else"). Whether that is better? ...ctd

...ctd. This post may also be of interest (where @whuber uses the $\chi^2$ residuals to "interpret" a Fisher exact result https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232187/fishers-exact-test-help-understanding-the-p-value

I should have been more precise in my earlier comment. Under the null of independence of row and column effects, plus the usual assumptions, the count in a cell will be hypergeometric. (It's deviation from that null you're interested in 'measuring')
